# Cannot find an OLD Gravity Form on an OLD Word Press site

Tags: wp-admin, forms, admin-menu, embed, plugin-gravity-forms

I am not a regular user of Word Press but I have recently been editing some Gravity Forms on our websites that feed data into Salesforce. On the Admin page, there is a tab for "Forms" with subtabs for "Entries", "Salesforce" (for fields mapping), etc. There is also a tab for "Pages" into which a form can be embedded.

[image: Original Website with GF]

I found out about another of our websites running on WordPress 4.8.7, however, that contains one Gravity Form, but I cannot figure out how to edit the form, or even find it on the back end. There is no "Forms" tab, no indication that Gravity Forms is installed, and even the page that hosts the form looks completely different in the back end from what appears online. I can't find any embed code on the page.

[image]

Can anyone help me to find this plugin? Or navigate the older wordpress admin UI? Thank you.

Comment: I don't need help with the plugin itself, but rather where to access the plugin in an unfamiliar admin menu.

Comment: "Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming. It’s Time for That to Change." https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that there should be a Gravity Forms in your plugin folder, assuming it's not part of a theme.

You could try installing the latest version of Gravity Forms plugin via Add Plugins, and see if you can then get into editing the forms. There should be an entry on the Settings menu (assuming you are admin-level).

Or, it could be that the access level for editing forms is set wrongly. I'd check to see if it exists in the plugins folder, install it if it doesn't, and go from there.

If there is a compatibility issue between the latest version and your WP version, then you could go to the Development area of the plugin (via the plugin page) and try downloading/installing an older version.